# SQL 2016: OPENDATASOURCE Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT MAX(VersionNumber)
FROM OPENDATASOURCE(
    'SQLNCLI',
    'Data Source = I.P.V.4;User ID = sa;Password = pswd;catalog=MyDB'
    ).MyDB.dbo.tbl_Version
```

results in a "speak to the red-hand" error that does not occur on over 20 other remote SQL instances inquired-of from the same source SQL instance:

> *Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot process the object ""MyDB"."dbo"."tbl_Version"". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for
>   linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns
>   or the current user does not have permissions on that object.*

Source is SQL 2016, targets vary from 2008R2, 2012, 2014 up to 2016 SP1 CU2, Enterprise and Standard Editions.

I used Idera's SQL Admin Toolset to get the server configurations from a working baseline instance, and compare it to 2 working instances, and 3 non-working instances.

All 3 of the latter reside in a Hong Kong Rackspace datacenter.  The working instances are in either a US or a UK Rackspace datacenter.

Aside from the collation of the non-working instances being different, there are no differences of merit (MAXDOP and MAXMEM don't count).

I also used that toolset's SQL Database Configuration tool and set the baseline as a working 2016 DB, then compared it to another working instance's 2014 DB, and the not-working 2016 DB - the only difference is the SQL Compatibility Level.

Ad Hoc Distributed Queries is running "ON", on all servers.

All 3 client protocols are enabled.  All TCP/IP configurations in SQL Client configs are identical.

I can connect via SSMS from my laptop using the I.P. of the not-working instance, using the same SQL login and password, and run a `SELECT *` from the same table, and get all rows.  I can see everything via SSMS.

I opened Server Objects/Linked Servers/Providers/SQLNCLI11 and looked at the properties on working and non-working instances - identical - the `DisallowAdhocAccess` setting is "OFF".

Although BOL doesn't state that after the `RECONFIGURE` to set the `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries` config to "ON", one must restart SQL, is this an omission/something that is really "required"?

Having Googled for the Msg line, plus most of the error text and found just 10 hits, none of which are useful, I took out the text message and still found nothing relevant that includes the "Msg 7357" portion.

Does anyone suspect a firewall issue? I doubt that because I can get through with SSMS, as I said above...

What (else) am I missing?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue...

The table is no longer a table - it's a SYNONYM over the same table schema that has moved to a named schema from dbo, and has a new name: SystemVersion.  OLE DB provider choked! (SQLNCLI or SQLOLEDB)